# How can I build `ungoogled-chromium` from source on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, compiling, chromium

I've put in about an hour at this point, and I'm starting to feel a bit dead inside.

I started by downloading `ungoogled-chromium` version 71.0.3578.98-2 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/tags). I extracted the `tar.gz` file into my home folder. Then, using the instructions from the "Any Linux Distribution" section of [the build instructions](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/blob/master/docs/building.md#any-linux-distribution). I followed the instructions to the point of adding [the LLVM APT repo.](https://apt.llvm.org/) I added the specified lines for Bionic (18.04) to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, retrieved the key with:

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

This output [these errors](https://pastebin.com/ZMzdq1B8) which look like this:

```
E: The repository 'https:/dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://apt.llvm.org/bionic llvm-toolchain-bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 15CF4D18AF4F7421
```

I then, (though I knew it wouldn't work), ran:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-8 lld-8 llvm-8-dev python python3 ninja-build
```

and all of the LLVM packages were not able to be installed.

This is my first experience building from source, so I know inevitably made some obnoxious novice mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, if you don't want to build from source they provide binaries already built for Ubuntu 18.04:

- https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/

Instructions for building are available from:

- https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/blob/master/docs/building.md#debian-and-its-derivatives

This specifies that you can build LLVM 7 and don't need to install LLVM 8 to build for Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)

Building should be as simple as:

```
sudo apt install packaging-dev python3 ninja-build

# Run from inside the clone of the repository
mkdir -p build/src

./get_package.py PACKAGE_TYPE_HERE build/src/debian
cd build/src

# Use dpkg-checkbuilddeps (from dpkg-dev) or mk-build-deps (from devscripts) to check for additional packages.
# If necessary, change the dependencies in debian/control to accommodate your environment.
# If necessary, modify AR, NM, CC, and CXX variables in debian/rules
debian/rules setup-local-src
dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```