# Install ungoogled-chromium using binaries

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, chromium, deb

As a follow-up to someone else's question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105699/how-can-i-build-ungoogled-chromium-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04/1105708#1105708) I was wondering if someone could help me by walking me through an install of ungoogled chromium via binaries. I am a total ubuntu newbie, and most of you will probably laugh but where do I start? Here are the [binaries](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/releases/ubuntu/cosmic_amd64/71.0.3578.98-2), as another user pointed out, in aforementioned question.

I tried building this locally following their instructions ([github](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium/blob/master/docs/building.md#debian-and-its-derivatives)), but I think because I have an older machine (8gb RAM) I ran up against a wall, computer froze twice.

I also have tried `dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc` in the directory where I've downloaded all these binaries - and a ton of researching.

Which files do I need from that binaries list, where should I put them, and how to install from them?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Setting aside the computer freezing issue—and assuming, say, x64—the binaries consist of a .buildinfo, .changes, and a number of .deb files (common, driver, I10n, shell, etc). I suspect there's some confusion about how to install in this environment.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand the question. You DID follow the [instructions for Ubuntu](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-debian), didn't you? There are two **alternative ways** of doing the installation, either via installing the `.deb` packages OR via compiling. Which one of the two are you trying to follow?

Comment: If you want the program to be available to all users, you could use `cd /usr/local/bin`, then download the binaries there using `sudo wget` followed by the url for each. Then install them using `sudo dpkg -i ungoogled-chromium_*.deb ungoogled-chromium-common_*.deb`. If you want to install the driver, l10n, and shell, then just add those to your `dpkg -i` list above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install one of these binaries, you just need to download the latest one:

```
wget https://github.com/riyad/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/releases/download/71.0.3578.98-2/ungoogled-chromium-common_71.0.3578.98-2.cosmic_amd64.deb
```

And then, install it using:

```
sudo apt install ./ungoogled-chromium-common_71.0.3578.98-2.cosmic_amd64.deb
```

Good luck.